# Global variables not saved after executing R code

Tags: r, active-directory, rstudio

Recently I swapped my personal PC with admin rights to my employee's PC, where we use AD to log in and where I do not hold admin rights.

Since that event, I have trouble running my R code. I currently develop Shiny app. Each time I click "Run app", two things appear to behave differently versus my old setup.

First of all, **I can run app only once** - after that, the Rstudio is busy forever, suppressing me from running app again, accessing data frames created by my app and so on. So after each test of some changes, I literally have to reset entire RStudio.

Secondly, despite the fact that I have set my working directory to "C:/Users/mylogin/Documents", after restarting R, there are **no global variables visible**, event after saving workspace image. I used to use global variables to debug my app after closing it. Of course I can rewrite entire code to, for example, dump all the tables to different files.

**My question is**: is it possible, that this behavior is related to not having admin rights on my current PC? Or is it related to another issue and if so - may someone provide me some help in that matter? I have little to no knowledge about debugging Rstudio.

**Setup:** Win 10 64bit, R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) Rstudio desktop, 1.3.1093, Apricot Nasturtium.

Comment: Doesn't seem like an R problem or an Active Directory problem.  Sounds like something related to Windows UAC. See if you can temporarily disable UAC, reboot, and try it again.

Comment: I can't disable UAC without admin rights, but I'll dig into it with our Service Desk, thanks for the clue.

Comment: I don't think "Global Variable" means what you think it means.  If you want to load an `.Rdata` -type file, you have to do so explicitly.    Be that as it may, you MUST post a simple, reproducible example of your code and your data for us to be able to help.

Comment: I meant global variable as in
 a <<- "new" 
I'm trying to reproduce my code, but in simpler example it seems to work. Still my app works on server side, on my private PC and seems to be buggy on office PC.

And now, as I write this comment, I switched view from Global Environment to one of packages and back and all the variables appeared. The session is still busy though, really weird.

Answer (score 0):

For future generations: the problem perished, without any particular reason, quite frustrating that we will never know the answer.